# Frêchet differentiability of the composition on a suitable Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a real Banach space included in the space of functions $C^1$ of $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ and and $T:E\to E$ defined by $T(f)=f\circ f$. I am looking for an example of space E such that T is differentiable on E.

By developing, $T(f+h)$ we find

$$T(f(x)+h(x))=f(f(x))+h(f(x))+f'(f(x)).h(x)+h'(f(x)).h(x)+o(h(x))$$
but the term $h'(f(x)).h(x)$ is not linear on h and it seems that $DT_{f}\left(h\right)=\left(f'\circ f\right)\times h+\left(h\circ f\right)$ but we need a space where $(h'\circ f).h=o(h)$

I thought of the subspace of $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ formed of bounded functions of which all derivatives are bounded, provided with the norm $f\mapsto \|f\|_{\infty} + \|f'\|_{\infty}$ but this space is not complete  space

edit

As suggested by  Giorgio Metafune , I start with  Gateaux differentiability . Let
$E=C_b$ (bounded and continuous functions with the sup-norm). Let $g\in E$ and f be a function derivable on $\mathbb R$. By developping
$$ (T(f+tg)-T(f))(x)=f(f(x)+tg(x))+tg(f(x)+tg(x))-f(f(x)) 
$$  then   $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(T(f+tg)-T(f))(x)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(f(x)+tg(x))-f(f(x)) }{t}+g(f(x))\\= f'(f(x)).g(x)+g(f(x)) $$

Then $$\qquad D_G(T)f(g)=g (f'\circ f)+g\circ f$$ and  $g\to D_G(T)f(g)$ is linear. It's must be continuous to deduce Frechet differentiability

**Update question** Giorgio Metafune suggests considering $E=C_0(\mathbb R)$

Let $E=C_0(\mathbb R)$ and $T: E\to E$ defined by $T(f)=f\circ f$. Show ( if true) that T is Fréchet differentiable at  all $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$. Can some one help me or give answer

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using finite dimensional examples, like the subspace of linear functions?

Comment: the linear case no interesting to me

Comment: Why not use $C^1_b$, the space of all bounded diferentiable functions, with bounded derivatives, with the norm you wrote in the last line?

Comment: @Giorgio Metafune $ C^1_b$ is not complete with this norm. I need Banach space!

Comment: If by $C^1_b$ we understand  the space  of bounded and differentiable functions with bounded first derivatives, it Is complete under your norm.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to say that $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ is not complete. there is a problem with your space $C^1_b$ because $\left(f'\circ f\right)\times h$ is not necessarily in E (f must be twice differentiable)

Comment: there is also another problem, f is differentiable $\iff $ $h'\to 0$ if $h\to 0$ but the fact that $h \to 0$ according to this norm does not imply that $h'\to  0$, because nothing is known about $h''$.

Comment: I see. Maybe it is better to look first at Gateaux differentiability and it is possible that your map has a derivative only at certain points $f$ and along certain "directions" $h$. If we consider $C_b$ (bounded and continuous functions with the sup-norm), maybe it is differentiable when $f \in C^1_b$ and along directions $h \in C^1_b$, too. The choice of $C_b$ should simplify the handling of the non linear part.

Comment: @Giorgio Metafune you can see my update  for Gateaux-dfferentiability and after ?

Comment: Seen. It seems that the map is Gateaux differentiable exactly at points $f \in C_1$. Maybe it is Frechet differentiable at the same points. It could be easier to work in $C_0$ instead of $C_b$ (functions vanishing at $\infty$), since uniform continuity holds for free.

Comment: I changed the question of the thread following your last remark

Comment: For reasons already pointed out, you would need to control the norm of the derivative by the norm of the function (to deal with the $h'(f(x))$ term). This essentially rules out most of the usual function spaces. You can come up with examples in spaces of analytic functions. For instance, if you consider bounded analytic functions on the disk, and f maps to a smaller disk, you can indeed bound $h'(f(x))$ by the norm of h.